# Change Chrome homepage(s) based on time of day

Tags: windows, ubuntu, google-chrome, homepage

I always forget to clock in on our web-based timeclock in the morning. In the past I've used a geofence reminder on my phone to remind me when I get to the office, but sometimes I start my day elsewhere and clock in there.

The first thing I do in the morning is check my email and admin dashboard, and those are my Chrome homepages. I thought it would be helpful if my homepage was the timeclock page, but I don't want it to always be my homepage. Only between the hours of 8:30 - 10 AM.

How would I go about setting my homepage to be a certain page between certain hours of the day? I'm using ubuntu, but doing it in Windows would be just as helpful.

Comment: Instead of setting the homepage, couldn't you just set a scheduled job to open the website at a certain time?

Comment: I assume using a calendar reminder isn't a solution?  You do it a couple dozen times and you likely wouldn't need it in the future.

Comment: I would do it based on calendar reminder, but I don't always end up at the office at the same time every day. And I'm ***very*** forgetful :)

Comment: A calendar appointment from 8-10 would be pretty persistent. What do you expect to accomplish with a homepage based on time if you're not always going to "end up in the office at the same time"? I don't understand how this is different than using a calendar.

Comment: On a different note, I think this might be a good question on *strategy* over at http://productivity.stackexchange.com/ rather than finding a technical solution.

Comment: @Raystafarian True, I'll consider asking a similar question there. To answer your first question, I figured the homepage solution would be more personally helpful because my routine is to immediately open Chrome when I sit down. And I don't use any desktop calendar software (only Google calendars). I'll try to work out a calendar solution though in the meantime if there aren't any answers posted here.

Comment: I think you *might* be able to find a chrome extension that does this, but it's not a standard feature of chrome. I, unfortunately, don't know of an extension. Maybe http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ would have a solution more elegant than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... why don't you try to create a `local` homepage on your hard disk, with an automatic redirection that depends from the time? 
Here below an example that open new tabs (or windows).  It's just an idea (and my 1st attempt with javascript) but it seems it function...

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo2">Smile</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function RedirectHompage() 
  {
    var time=new Date().getHours();
    if ( (time>8) && (time<10)){
      // Change the link below with the ones you prefer    
      setTimeout( function() { window.open( 'https://www.google.com','_blank');}, 500);
      setTimeout( function() { window.open( 'http://www.excite.com','_blank');}, 1000);
      }
   else {
      // Normal time of the day: work!   
      setTimeout(function() { window.open( 'http://www.yahoo.com','_blank');}, 1000);
      }
  }
  window.onload = RedirectHompage;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To redirect automatically it is possible to use:

`window.location.href = "http://www.altavista.com";`

Comment: How do you program Chrome to load those local page?

Comment: The idea, almost 10 years old, was to write that script in a local page and then **set that page as your home page**... So every time you open Chrome on your home page the code inside will be executed. I check with Chromium and it still works...